# What will be the minimum required jars for Arquillian testing

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss-arquillian

thanks for viewing this.

Our project is planing to use arquillian in integration test.
But we should report to client which jar files we use and for what we need it.

Maven downloads several jar files which seems not necessary and I cannot explain what they are.

Simple google search shows the site below, but information inside seems like about JBoss 5.1. 
http://jdevelopment.nl/integration-testing-arquillian-maven/

Does somebody know which jar files are minimum requirement?

Our container is JBoss EAP 6.2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that You are working with maven : You could run mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose on Your project and that's it.

Gradle offers a similar feature by running gradle dependencies

You should not manually remove jar files from the list because that might lead You into unwanted runtime errors.

The benefit of dependency resolution is, that You have all required dependencies that your component needs, including the dependents of these depenencies and I strongly recommend You to rely on the dependency resolution. Arquillian offers afaik a BOM and a core module, the servers type is added by just adding the matching arquillian jar file. To find out which module requires which jar You apparently can just try it by enabling and disabling dependencies in Your build file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But our client requirement is, I need to clarify which jar file does what tasks. Is there any way to find out it?

Comment: well, I understand, but what Your client demands is comparable to justify the alloys of the engine by a vehicle vendor. The only thing You can do is to plot the dependency tree and comment each jar file then.